# Why does adding a concatenation break this MS ACCESS "SQL" query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Here are the table involved

```
O (for origin): | PText | CText |
P (products):     | id | PText | ... |
C (category):     | id | CText | .... |
D (destination):  | pid | cid |
```

What I need to do is to find a product ids using O's PText and category ids using O's CTexts, and put these ids into D

This query does exactly that:

```
INSERT INTO D ( pid, cid )
SELECT P.id, C.id
FROM (O INNER JOIN P ON O.PText = P.PText) INNER JOIN C ON C.CText = O.CText
WHERE P.id IS NOT NULL AND C.id IS NOT NULL AND P.id NOT IN (SELECT pid FROM D);
```

The problem is that O has a few mistakes. All the PTexts are missing a "0" in front (Microsoft decided to take it away when taking data from an Access table and putting it in a Excel spreadsheet). Therefore, the PText doesn't match, but "0"+PText does match.

Here is my second attempt:

```
INSERT INTO D ( pid, cid )
SELECT P.id, C.id
FROM (O INNER JOIN P ON **"0" &** O.PText = P.PText) INNER JOIN C ON C.CText = O.CText
WHERE P.id IS NOT NULL AND C.id IS NOT NULL AND P.id NOT IN (SELECT pid FROM D);
```

This second query doesn't work. It says **You are about to update 0 row(s).**
My Question: How can the second query not work when the first one does?

Note: this is using MS ACCESS 2002

Comment: does `"0" & O.Number` turn the whole thing into a string? which you're then trying to put in a number field?

Comment: @Andrea duh, absolutely. The "Number" is textual though, as it sometimes has dashes and the such. I edited my question to correct my mistake.

Comment: Does this return any results:  SELECT O.id, M.id 
FROM (O INNER JOIN M ON "0" & O.PText = M.PText);

Comment: Just to be clear: MS didn't "decide to take it away". Your Excel cell was not clearly identified as text (starting with a `'` if the content is numeric, or explicitly selected and assigned the text format), and the export assumed it was a numeric value instead. Since *numeric* integer values don't contain leading zeroes, they were dropped during the conversion.

Answer (score 3):

Both queries are probably working.  The second one simply isn't finding any rows to UPDATE.  The reason is likely that when you massage the O.TEXT field by adding an initial "0" character to it then the INNER JOIN fails to match any records in M.

Try the query:

```
 SELECT M.id, C.id FROM (O INNER JOIN M ON "0" & O.PText = M.PText)
```

Does it return records?  If not, that's your problem.

Try this:

```
 SELECT M.PText, C.PText FROM (O INNER JOIN M ON O.PText = M.PText)
```

What gets returned?  (I'm not sure I kept up with the changes you made to the column names, you may need to modify them before running the query).

Comment: That query doesn't find much. I have found some myself though, looking through the tables..

Comment: If the that query can't find them, your UPDATE query can't, either.  Since there are more conditions in your original query, if the smaller query above returns a few records the additional conditions may well eliminate them, leaving you with no records to update.  Why are you doing the concatenation?

Comment: because I know by looking at the tables that if the Ptexts are to match, I need to add a "0" in front of those in O. This being due to the problematic port from Access to Excel... Did I understand your question correctly?

Comment: You do, but it looks like when you add the `0` the TEXTs do not match but, when you do it *without* the leading `0` they *do* match.  Also, of course, be aware of letter `O` versus number `0`.

Comment: Do you mean that the first query could have matched "1234" with "01234" even though they are declared as text (but using the `=` operator)? That would certainly explain what I'm seeing.

Comment: No, that shouldn't happen unless you're casting or converting to INT somewhere.  What I'm suggesting is that the fields you're comparing in the query have the value "1234" in both fields and that the "01234" you're seeing must be in some other field.

Comment: Oh, no then, is really is 01234

Comment: I do get results for that second query comparer Category texts

Comment: What are the values of M.PText and C.PText return from that second query?  If they're the same (eg, "1234") then those are the values stored in your table, not "01234".  Or do you think there are records in M with *both* "1234" and "01234"?

Comment: There is no such thing as C.PText. I'm sorry I've been messing up the column names from the start. I edited the original question with the correct names. I can find all the O.CText = C.CText, but none of the O.PText = P.PText

Answer (score 0):

Number is probably a number field, thats why the leading zero is stript. You concat will make it a "text" field and you can't join text vs number column.

Comment: Column is shown to be declared as TEXT despite it's (original) name of Number in the question.

Comment: @madC Shouldn't I be getting a syntax error in that case? Also, see my edited question, the number field is actually text..

Comment: @Shawn Sadly i don't have access 2002 available. I've tested in access 2007 and didn't get a syntax error and the join succeeded anyway.